# About different ways of calling a static class in delphi

Tags: delphi, class, constructor

I am creating a class with class constructor

```
TStaticDynSettings = class
public
  class constructor create;
  class destructor destroy;
  class procedure Reload;
end;
```

Do all the other method in the class apart from create and destroy need to be a class methods?

I know for sure all the variables need to be a class var else the automatic initialization wont work.

what is the difference in calling the procedure as?..

```
var StDyn : TStaticDynSettings;`
StDyn.Reload;
```

and

`TStaticDynSettings.Reload;`

Comment: One of us is misinformed about restrictions imposed on classes with class constructors and destructors. I see [nothing documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Methods#Class_Constructors) that such classes cannot have instance fields or virtual methods. Where did you read that such things aren't allowed? If, as I suspect, those features *are* allowed, then does your question actually have any meaning at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - If you are not planning to create object instances of `TStaticDynSettings` you can use any of 3 forms:

```
type
  TStaticDynSettings = class
  public
    procedure Reload1;
    class procedure Reload2;
    class procedure Reload3; static;
  end;
```

call examples:

```
procedure Call1;
var Instance: TStaticDynSettings;

begin
  Instance.Reload1;
end;

procedure Call2;
begin
  TStaticDynSettings.Reload2;
end;

procedure Call3;
begin
  TStaticDynSettings.Reload3;
end;
```

The difference is a hidden argument passed in `Reload1` and `Reload2` methods and not passed in `Reload3`.

The hidden argument is a reference to object instance in `Reload1` (and not used since you are not creating object instance), and a class reference in `Reload2` (which probably also unnecessary in your case, assuming a class reference is known at compile time).

The first form (`Reload1`) is misleading because it assumes using an object reference and so should be avoided (though it works).

The third form (`Reload3`) is preferable if you are not using class references that are unknown at compile time.

2 - There is no difference (not counting an overhead of using unnecessary object variable if the first case).

Comment: I feel like you haven't actually answered the first question. Or, by suggesting that `Reload1` is a valid choice, did you mean to implicitly answer the question *no*? I don't think you should recommend declaring instance methods that are intended to be called on invalid instance references.

Comment: Hi serg i dint get what you mean by reload3 how come the class references will be unknown at compile time. only when we go for VMT(polymorhism) then it is unknown at compile time but we cant have VMT in the class which contain class constructor. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @SreeRaghavan - that is a different story; you can declare a class procedure (ex `Reload2`) as virtual, so I guess there is some kind of vtable responsible for it.

Comment: @RobKennedy - updated; it is not clear what is asked - 'should I use?' or 'will it work?'

Comment: @serg i feel reload3 is the proper way of calling other class functions inside singleton class.Thx

Comment: Serg, the hidden parameter in fact is different in Reload1 and Reload2! The first time it's a pointer to "self" which is effectly the pointer to the "instance" variable in the reload1 case. But if you are referencing to a "class" then self always points to the class structure itself. So in SreeRaghavan's case there is no difference in the class procedure calls. Both self params will point to the class structure (not the instance).

Comment: There are two question marks in the post, indicating the two questions. The first asks, "Do all the other method in the class apart from create and destroy need to be a class methods?" It's not clear to me whether your answer to that question is *yes* or *no*.